# Reading a web page in a foreign language with StreamReader

Tags: c#, http, encoding, streamreader

I'm trying to fetch a web page that is a mix of English and Korean. The browser can fetch and display the page just fine, but when I try to grab it programmatically I can't get the Korean characters to display properly.

I know that you can specify an Encoding in the StreamReader but I haven't found one that works yet.

This is the code that I'm using to read the response:

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
```

response.CharacterSet returns UTF8. I've also tried all of the basic encoding options - ASCII, BigEndian, Default, Unicode, UTF32, UTF7, and manually adding Encoding.UTF8.

I've also tried going about it through the CultureInfo:

```
CultureInfo kr = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ko");
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding(kr.TextInfo.ANSICodePage));
```

using both "ko" and "ko-KR". I get varied results from all these different types, but none of them are correct.

I've also tried the code page directly:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding(949));
```

`response.ContentEncoding` returns an empty string. I'm running out of ideas.

Edit: Here is an example of what I'm expecting:

프로젝트:

and here is what I'm getting:

```
        //ASCII == ??????
        //BigEndian == à¤¼æ±©æ¹«â¨ç‰¥æ˜½âˆ¯æ©³â½¤ç°æ”
        //Default == Ã­â€â€žÃ«Â¡Å“Ã¬Â ÂÃ­Å Â¸:
        //Unicode == Ã­â€â€žÃ«Â¡Å“Ã¬Â ÂÃ­Å Â¸
        //UTF32 == ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï
        //UTF7 == Ã­Â”Â„Ã«Â¡ÂœÃ¬Â ÂÃ­ÂŠÂ¸
        //UTF8 == í”„ë¡œì íŠ¸
```

Comment: You say it doesn't display properly, but you're not showing the display code.

Comment: What headers are you sending with the HTTP request? Compare this with what the browser is sending (Fiddler is very helpful for things like this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW: a stream reader is likely not going to work well.

Prefer using [HttpWebRequest Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to do browser requests (or you will start feeling sorry very soon when you get 302 responses or gzipped and/or chunked encoding)

I promoted this to an answer, as it *might* very well be the problem you're having already. I don't know *what* the response you are getting looks like, of course

Comment: I am using HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse classes - and then using StreamReader to read the resonse stream from the HttpWebResponse.